# Порваный аккордеон

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт "аккордеон", но без функции сворачивания уже "открытого" блока, т.е. кликая по ul.acc-title должен открываться один блок и закрываться другой (если открыт).

Не могу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на один элемент другие сворачивались.
Буду очень благодарен за возможные решения.

```
<div class="scroll-container">
    <div class="accordion">
        <ul class="acc-title">
            <li>title 1</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="fine">content 1</div>
        <ul class="acc-title">
            <li>title 2</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="fine">content 2</div>
    </div><!-- .accordion -->
</div><!-- .scroll-container -->

$(window).load(function () {
    $(".scroll-container").customScrollbar();
    $(".viewport").css("width", "540px");
    $(".accordion > ul.table-acc-title").click(function (el) {
        //console.log($(el.target).parent().next());
        //var toExpand = $(this).siblings(".fine");
        var toExpand = $(el.target).parent().next();
        var link = $(this);
        if (toExpand.is(":visible"))
            toExpand.slideUp(200, function () {
                resizeAndScroll(link);
            });
        else
            toExpand.slideDown(200, function () {
                resizeAndScroll(link);
            });

    });
});
function resizeAndScroll(elem) {
    $(".scroll-container").customScrollbar("resize", true)
    $(".viewport").css("width", "540px");
}
```

Надеюсь кто-то поймет этот поток мысли. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все просто, тебе надо перед открыванием закрывать все остальные, и открывать текущую.

```
$(".accordion > ul.acc-title").click(function (el) {
    var allExpand = $(el.target).parent().siblings(),
        toExpand  = $(el.target).parent().next(),
        link = $(this);
    allExpand.slideDown(200, function () {
        resizeAndScroll(link);
    });
    toExpand.slideUp(200, function () {
        resizeAndScroll(link);
    });
});
```

Если правильно понимаю твою иерархию

Comment: Спасибо что уделяете время, все так, нужно закрывать все открытые.
к сожалению данная конструкция не работает :(
я отредактировал вопрос, для большей наглядности

Comment: я конечно не вкурсе зечем такая конструкция, но мне кажется что она не много логически не верная =( посмотри на этот вариант
[jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/faqupayawi/1/)

Comment: вариант отличный, но к сожалению у меня другая конструкция.
**ul** это и есть титул и после каждого **ul** идет свой **.fine**. Kликая на **ul**, под ним открывается **div.fine**, который отодвигает остальные **ul** ниже, когда он это делает, пересчитывается размер блока **.scroll-container**.

как-то так(